# Displayed ComboBox Items not updating

Tags: wpf, combobox, refresh

I have a problem with the List of Items in a combobox. They dont update when the itemsource is reloaded (from a file)

The WPF looks like this:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="Dock_Profil" DataContext="{Binding Profile, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated= True}">
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ComboBox Margin="5" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  DisplayMemberPath="ProfilName" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                  x:Name="cmbProfil" SelectedIndex="0" ></ComboBox>
                        <Button Margin="5">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <Image Margin="2" Stretch="None" Source="/MEC_EDINeu;component/Resources/Add24.png" />
                                <Label>Neues Profil</Label>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
```

The Property Profile is this type:

```
Public Class EDIProfile
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of EDIProfil)
```

At certain points i need to reload the Content of Profile so

```
Profile.Load()
OnPropertyChanged("Profile")
```

is called. (OnPropertyChanged is implemented in the ViewModelBase.vb and passed on to MainWindowViewModel)

When i check afterwards in the MainWindow.xaml.vb using:

```
For Each item As EDIProfil In cmbProfil.Items
            MsgBox(item.ProfilName & "__" & item.lastFA)
        Next
```

the correct items are in there.

But the combobox in GUI still shows the old content.

---

A Workaround i found (but i dont want to use that for all comboboxes):
if i (in mainwindow.xaml.vb) use that line:

```
cmbProfil.Items.Refresh()
```

the update of the items displayed by the combobox work (but shouldnt the binding to that?)

---

I am pretty new to WPF, hoping to get some help here.

Thanks in advance

---

When I load the data in MainWindowViewModel (is that the correct way to do it anyway?):

```
Public Sub loadProfile()
        'Profile.Load()
        Profile.Clear()
        Dim xmls As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(EDIProfile))
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Substring(0, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.LastIndexOf("\") + 1) & "EDIProfile.xml")
        Dim temp As New EDIProfile
        '  MsgBox("KK")
        temp = xmls.Deserialize(reader)
        For Each item As EDIProfil In temp
            Profile.Add(item)
        Next
        reader.Close()
        OnPropertyChanged("Profile")

    End Sub
```

It works

Comment: if i dont open the combobox before i reload the items, they are displayed correctly.

Comment: Are you using any kind of multi-threading to update your ComboBox?

Comment: Does your custom `EDIProfile` class overwrite any of the base `ObservableCollection` methods?

Comment: @Rachel no no overwritten functions.
but i had a load function in the class. after i moved the loading into the mainwindowviewmodel it seems to work.
with the latest addition (see last edit very bottom of the original post) it even works without the onpropertychanged("profile") as i guess the observable collection does the job.
changes to the data made within the class dont get passed to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... remove your DataContext binding and bind ItemsSource directly to `Profile`.

```
   <DockPanel x:Name="Dock_Profil">
       <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                   Orientation="Horizontal">
           <ComboBox Margin="5"
                     Width="200"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Profile,  
                                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                           NotifyOnSourceUpdated= True}"   ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, but tried that already (and it did not change the behavior) and the datacontext is used for other elements within the dockpanel as well.